# Where is windows installer exe code of llvm in the repository

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, llvm

Where directory is location of windows installer code in llvm?
I want to learn about structure of windows installer, but I don't know where is it.
I asked about text corruption caused on llvm installer. ([Text corruption in LLVM 7.0.1 installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946313/text-corruption-in-llvm-7-0-1-installer/))
So I am interested in why it caused.
Where it located in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by myself:

see https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/088520252029a2d686d8c426f73113da32f51f39/utils/release/build_llvm_package.bat

Above is a batch file for build the installer.